# How can I use Laravel's validation rules to combine a required_if and required_without rule, with array fields?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-9

In our context, if a site is not manned 24 hours a day we require a contact number. It can either be a landline number or a mobile number. So the rules I am trying to apply look like this.

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'sites.*.manned_24_hours_a_day' => 'required|boolean',
        'sites.*.contacts.*.landline_number' => 'required_if:sites.*.manned_24_hours_a_day,false|required_without:sites.*.contacts.*.mobile_number',
        'sites.*.contacts.*.mobile_number' => 'required_if:sites.*.manned_24_hours_a_day,false|required_without:sites.*.contacts.*.landline_number',
    ];
}
```

With a single site, this seems straightforward but there will be multiple sites submitted so this is where I'm coming unstuck.

The rule I'm trying to achieve is the landline number is required if the site is not manned 24/7, and the mobile number is empty. And vice versa.

I have tried to incorporate a callback function using `Rule::requiredIf` but I can't seem to capture the specific index of the array I want to validate against. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to incorporate dot notation into a callback validation rule.

Comment: If you need to check against a specific index, you can't use `.*.`. A simple way to handle this is looping over your `$request->input('sites')` array and constructing the rules as `'sites.0.manned_24_hours_a_day' => 'required|boolean'`, (where `0` will be the array index, so 0 through X). Yours is a bit more complicated due to nested arrays `sites -> contacts`, but the general rule of thumb is if you need to compare a rule with another value, `*` wildcards don't work...

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis, manually building up the `$rules` array seems to be the best approach. Tried this out and is working perfectly, thanks for your input!

Comment: Excellent! If you'd like, you may add a self-answer in the section below, as this might help others with similar problems, but otherwise, glad to hear you've got it working 

Comment: What was the answer? Can you please add it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up looping through the sites (from the request) as suggested by Tim and constructing each rule manually.

So, rather than using the `sites.*.contacts` notation, I explicitly build up rules like this:

```php
$index = 0; // This increments for each site
$i = 0; // This increments for each contact

$rules += [
    'sites.' . $index . '.manned_24_hours_a_day' => 'required|boolean',
    'sites.' . $index . '.contacts.' . $i . '.landline_number' => 'required_without:sites.' . $index . '.contacts.' . $i . '.mobile_number',
    'sites.' . $index . '.contacts.' . $i . '.mobile_number' => 'required_without:sites.' . $index . '.contacts.' . $i . '.landline_number',
];
```